# creating an identical copy of a SAS dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is here there a way to create an identical copy of a dataset that includes all the column labels, formats,  indexes and constaints?
I'm aware that the below datasep copy would create a copy of the dataset, but this would not retail the constaints, and index.

```
data work.new_table;
set work.old_table;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [PROC DATASETS](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1juxu16zautpxn1dikxecc3kn7w.htm), COPY with the CONSTRAINT and INDEX specifications.

```
proc datasets lib=work nodetails nolist;
copy in=work out=want constraint=yes index=yes;
select datasetName;
run;quit;
```

Comment: thanks @Reeza. In my case the datasets have to be in the same library, ie in and out both are work. This case, the code do not work. Also,  the new dataset that is created need to have a different name for example datasetName2.  Are there any alternative approach?

Comment: Right click on a dataset name in SAS Studio has a Duplicate dataset option. Is there a programmatic equivalent for this action?